# flatten grouped elements akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have following flows

```
Flow[D]
   .map...
    .groupBy..
    .grouped(30)
    .via(flowN)
    mergeSubstreams
```

After mergeSubstreams I want to flatten flow .
I couldn't find a away to do it
any help please?

Comment: What's the type of `flowN`?

Comment: What is the result of the above code? Flow of Flows, Flow of Sources?

Comment: Have you tried `fold`?